# Adding an Application controller to android project?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Following a volley android tutorial I am trying to figure out how to get it to work, it keeps crashing. I don't think I included the Application class correctly.
http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/

I am not getting any errors, but the app is crashing, I need to inspect logcat further, but I am asking if the code is implemented correctly.

**app/java/co.mystuff.CoolApp/MainActivity.java**

```
package co.mystuff.CoolApp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Make call
        final String URL = "http://api.dribbble.com/shots/everyone";
        // pass second argument as "null" for GET requests
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        // add the request object to the queue to be executed
        ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**app/java/co.mystuff.CoolApp/ApplicationController.java**

```
package co.mystuff.CoolApp;

import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

/**
 * Created by Michael on 6/17/2015.
 */
public class ApplicationController extends Application {

    /**
     * Log or request TAG
     */
    public static final String TAG = "VolleyPatterns";

    /**
     * Global request queue for Volley
     */
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    /**
     * A singleton instance of the application class for easy access in other places
     */
    private static ApplicationController sInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // initialize the singleton
        sInstance = this;
    }

    /**
     * @return co.pixelmatter.meme.ApplicationController singleton instance
     */
    public static synchronized ApplicationController getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    /**
     * @return The Volley Request queue, the queue will be created if it is null
     */
    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        // lazy initialize the request queue, the queue instance will be
        // created when it is accessed for the first time
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified request to the global queue, if tag is specified
     * then it is used else Default TAG is used.
     *
     * @param req
     * @param tag
     */
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);

        VolleyLog.d("Adding request to queue: %s", req.getUrl());

        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified request to the global queue using the Default TAG.
     *
     * @param req
     * @param tag
     */
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TAG);

        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    /**
     * Cancels all pending requests by the specified TAG, it is important
     * to specify a TAG so that the pending/ongoing requests can be cancelled.
     *
     * @param tag
     */
    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you added the Controller ass appname into your manifest ? otherwise you receive a nullpointer because getInstance will return null

Comment: No I did not touch the manifest.

Comment: How do I add the java controller to the manifest? I am a noob, but learning. I remember vaguely having to add into the manifest.

Comment: '<application
        android:name="YOUR_Controller"....'
add is as property name in your application element inside the minifest. you need to provide the full path to it, so package and class name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't comment,
but did you add the following to your manifest?

```
<application
    android:name="co.mystuff.CoolApp.ApplicationController"
...
/>
```

Comment: No I am reading this http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/ so I just add that onto whats already there.

Comment: Looks like it works.. Thanks man I will green check you when I can