# Android: Best way to create Singleton POJO object in Android App

Tags: java, android, kotlin, singleton

I want to fetch an user object from Database and have a single instance of the same in whole application. What would be best and efficient way to first fetch from database on app initialisation and make it available for whole class.

I am using dagger in project, if that helps. I already have DatabaseManager(fetch user object from database) injected in AppModule

Comment: So how will you represent when the user is logged out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

create a MyApplicationController which extends Application(), instantiate your dagger in this class, through a static method return an instance of this class, then in activity do MyApplicationController.getInstance().getAppComponent().inject(this.activity)

Mark your provides method with @singleton or create your own scope annotation.
and most important add this to manifest file as your application class.

@Inject
User

As long as you only have one instance of MyApplicationController you'll always have the same User through all your app.

have a look at this as well. [Adding an Application controller to android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908734/adding-an-application-controller-to-android-project)